# Расшифровать текст методом частотного анализа

Tags: криптография

**Есть исходный зашифрованный текст, что за шифр или же ключи не знаю, но суть задания такая: используя метод частотного анализа расшифровать данный текст.**

**Сам текст:**

рхбжхп, 1975
— ощё кпёфщё фьхцбё! — яхбыибэ ж шпёфщи фщифбючэ фюьёстю — фщифбючэ ф щэтён фичён, сщё тёфщшцти кэчймхж кёвхчхчи. — рэ, фьхцбё, — кёжщёпичэ ёбэ. — ьён ьэчйсит фтэдэч, сщё бх кпищпэлижэчфш т зёьшстю, э ёб битёлрэ бх чяхщ!
тчэпхбф тёдлпёж юях цхфщй чхщ веч рипхтщёпёь оччиблщёбфтён фпхрбхн цтёче, э рё щёлё ржэрмэщй чхщ юсищхчйфщжёжэч, щэт сщё юя ёб-щё юьхч ёвпэыэщйфш ф пэффхпяхббеьи пёрищхчшьи, бё ощэ жефётэш зюрёыэжэш яхбыибэ и хх бхжёдьющиьен ёщкпефт — ёби жежёричи рипхтщёпэ ид фхвш…
— бё вечи фжирхщхчи… — жёдпэдич ёб.
— ьиффиф юищтёь бэлёжэпижэхщ бэ ьёхлё фебэ. тёпиб би дэ сщё ве бх кписибич жпхрэ зёьшстю. кпэжрэ, рёпёлён?
— кпэжрэ, ьэьючш, — кпёлёжёпич тёпиб эблхчйфтиь лёчёфтёь, бё кпи ощёь хлё зёчёрбех и бхьилэуыих лчэдэ кпифщэчйбё фьёщпхчи бэ рипхтщёпэ, фчёжбё ьэчйсит ёмхбижэч, тэтён оггхтщ кпёиджхч хлё ёщжхщ.
— жёщ жирищх! — щёпяхфщжюуых жёфтчитбючэ яхбыибэ.
— бё ьиффиф юищтёь…
— ёбэ щхпкхщй бх ьёяхщ тёпибэ, — кхпхвичэ рипхтщёпэ чувжхёвичйбэш ьэщй. — рэ, щхпкхщй бх ьёяхщ. ф фэьёлё кхпжёлё рбш. жэь фчхрюхщ рёкпэцижэщй хх, э бх ьёхлё пхвхбтэ! ржх бхрхчи бэдэр ш хн кпшьё ж чимё дэшжичэ: «бх дбэу, сщё же жвижэхщх ж лёчёже рпюлиз юсхбитёж, бё ш бх кёджёчу, сщёве же лёжёпичи ф ьёиь ьэчйситёь ё фхтфх!»— яхбыибэ кётёфичэфй бэ фебэ. — и жёщ жэь пхдючйщэщ, — рёвэжичэ ёбэ.
— ю ьиффиф юищтёь кпхтпэфбэш зэпэтщхпифщитэ. ёбэ битёлрэ ве фхвх бх кёджёчичэ…
— и щхь бх ьхбхх… — фбёжэ кхпхвичэ пэффхпяхббэш ьэщй. — бх юрижчуфй, хфчи ёбэ фэьэ ювичэ ощёлё зёьшстэ.
— зёьшт веч хх рёьэцбиь кищёьмхь. ёбэ кпибхфчэ хлё ж цтёчю, сщёве кпёрхьёбфщпипёжэщй…
— э кёщёь ждшчэ и ювичэ. лёфкёри, ё схь пхсй? тпефэ — ёбэ и хфщй тпефэ! бх кёбиьэу, ё схь ье фкёпиь? бисхлё фщпэцбёлё, рэях хфчи ве тёпиб ювич зёьштэ. зёщш ёб ощёлё бх рхчэч. кёньищх, ьёхлё фебэ дрхфй щпэжшщ. и рэжэнщх рёлёжёпиьфш: чивё же дэньхщхфй ощён ёфёвён, чивё дэбшщйфш кпирхщфш ьбх!
тёдлпёж фё ждрёзёь фбшч ёсти и кпибшчфш кпёщипэщй чибде. рипхтщёп кпхтпэфбё кёбиьэч, сщё рёчяхб тэтиь-щё ёвпэдёь бхнщпэчидёжэщй фирхжцюу кхпхр биь яхбыибю, кётэ ёбэ бх кёлювичэ тэпйхпю зёпёцхн юсищхчйбиме. южхыхжэщй — эвфёчущбё вхфкёчхдбё, кёфтёчйтю ьэщй ьэчйситэ бх яхчэхщ бисхлё фчюцэщй. сщё ях тэфэхщфш пхвхбтэ… хлё эблхчйфтин лёчёфёт фёжхпцхббё бх фёсхщэчфш ф кпифщэчйбеь чхршбеь ждлчшрёь.
— ье ьёяхь кёлёжёпищй бэхрибх? — кпёлёжёпич тёдлпёж. яхбыибэ, кёзёях, пэфщхпшчэфй.
— дэсхь? хфчи же бэрххщхфй ювхрищй ьхбш ж щёь, сщё ьён тёпиб…
— жфхлё ёрбю ьибющю, — кпёрёчяэч рипхтщёп, бэ фхн пэд кпёшжижцин бэфщёнсижёфщй. — кпёцю жэф, жфхлё чицй ьибющю…
— зёпёцё, — тижбючэ яхбыибэ. — тёпиб, рёпёлён, кёрёяри ьхбш ж тёпирёпх.
— ирю, ьэьёстэ.
тёдлпёж кёрбшчфш фё фщючэ и кчёщбё кпитпеч дэ ьэчйситёь ржхпй. шжбё жфщпхжёяхббэш, яхбыибэ кпикёрбшчэфй, бё рипхтщёп кпёлёжёпич:
— вюрйщх рёвпе, фирищх.
— ьён тёпиб…
— юфкётёнщхфй, ф биь бисхлё бх фчюсищфш. — тёдлпёж жхпбючфш т фщёчю и, бхьбёлё кёьёчсэж, фкпёфич:
— фтэяищх, жэь битёлрэ бх кпизёричё ж лёчёжю кётэдэщй фебэ зёпёцхью рхщфтёью кфизёчёлю?
— же ф юьэ фёцчи! — дэтписэчэ яхбыибэ, жфтэтижэш бэ бёли. — тёпибю бх бюяхб битэтён кфизёчёл! ёб эвфёчущбё дрёпёж! кпёвчхьэ бх ж бхь, э ж ощён фщхпжх! ш рёчябэ вечэ кпхржирхщй, сщё ьён кпизёр вхфкёчхдхб, сщё же кпиьхщх хх фщёпёбю.
— ш яхчэу тёпибю рёвпэ. — рипхтщёп фщэпэчфш фёзпэбшщй фкётёнфщжих. — фчюсэн ф зёьштёь — бх хрибфщжхббен. ж кёжхрхбии жэцхлё фебэ хфщй бхтёщёпех ёщтчёбхбиш…

**Проведя частотный анализ, получил следующие частоты букв:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Очевидно, что буква ё --> о.**
**Прямая замена символов ничего не дает, если кто-то сможет подсказать, что дальше делать?**

Comment: [дубликат (уже удалённый)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1551923/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0)

Comment: `Прямая замена символов ничего не дает` — очень даже даёт. если заменить все `ё` на `О` (верхний регистр для того, чтобы лучше в глаза бросалось), то можно сразу вычленить двухбуквенные слова `рО`, `щО`, `бО`, `фО`. и сделать вывод, что буквы `рщбф` — это какие-то из букв `ДНСТ`. ну а дальше дело техники и терпения. *gnu/sed* вам в помощь: `$ sed 'y/ёщ/ОТ/' файл`

Answer (score 5):

```
{'ё': 'о', 'х': 'е', 'э': 'а', 'и': 'и', 'б': 'н', 'ф': 'с', 'щ': 'т', 'п': 'р', 'ч': 'л', 'ж': 'в',
    'ь': 'м', 'т': 'к', 'р': 'д', 'к': 'п', 'ю': 'у', 'ш': 'я', 'л': 'г', 'й': 'ь', 'с': 'ч', 'е': 'ы',
    'в': 'б', 'д': 'з', 'я': 'ж', 'н': 'й', 'з': 'х', 'ц': 'ш', 'ы': 'щ', 'у': 'ю', 'о': 'э', 'м': 'ц',
    'г': 'ф'}
```

> денвер, 1975 — это просто смешно! — женщина в ярости стиснула сумочку — стиснула с такой силой, что костяшки пальцев побелели. — да, смешно, — повторила она. — мой мальчик сказал, что не притрагивался к хомячку, а он никогда не лжет! кларенс козгров уже шесть лет был директором эллингтонской средней школы, а до того двадцать лет учительствовал, так что уж он-то умел обращаться с рассерженными родителями, но эта высокая худощавая женщина и ее невозмутимый отпрыск — они выводили директора из себя… — но были свидетели… — возразил он. — миссис уитком наговаривает на моего сына. корин ни за что бы не причинил вреда хомячку. правда, дорогой? — правда, мамуля, — проговорил корин ангельским голоском, но при этом его холодные и немигающие глаза пристально смотрели на директора, словно мальчик оценивал, какой эффект произвел его ответ. — вот видите! — торжествующе воскликнула женщина. — но миссис уитком… — она терпеть не может корина, — перебила директора любвеобильная мать. — да, терпеть не может. с самого первого дня. вам следует допрашивать ее, а не моего ребенка! две недели назад я ей прямо в лицо заявила: «не знаю, что вы вбиваете в головы других учеников, но я не позволю, чтобы вы говорили с моим мальчиком о сексе!»— женщина покосилась на сына. — и вот вам результат, — добавила она. — у миссис уитком прекрасная характеристика. она никогда бы себе не позволила… — и тем не менее… — снова перебила рассерженная мать. — не удивлюсь, если она сама убила этого хомячка. — хомяк был ее домашним питомцем. она принесла его в школу, чтобы продемонстрировать… — а потом взяла и убила. господи, о чем речь? крыса — она и есть крыса! не понимаю, о чем мы спорим? ничего страшного, даже если бы корин убил хомяка. хотя он этого не делал. поймите, моего сына здесь травят. и давайте договоримся: либо вы займетесь этой особой, либо заняться придется мне! козгров со вздохом снял очки и принялся протирать линзы. директор прекрасно понимал, что должен каким-то образом нейтрализовать сидевшую перед ним женщину, пока она не погубила карьеру хорошей учительницы. увещевать — абсолютно бесполезно, поскольку мать мальчика не желает ничего слушать. что же касается ребенка… его ангельский голосок совершенно не сочетался с пристальным ледяным взглядом. — мы можем поговорить наедине? — проговорил козгров. женщина, похоже, растерялась. — зачем? если вы надеетесь убедить меня в том, что мой корин… — всего одну минуту, — продолжал директор, на сей раз проявивший настойчивость. — прошу вас, всего лишь минуту… — хорошо, — кивнула женщина. — корин, дорогой, подожди меня в коридоре. — иду, мамочка. козгров поднялся со стула и плотно прикрыл за мальчиком дверь. явно встревоженная, женщина приподнялась, но директор проговорил: — будьте добры, сидите. — мой корин… — успокойтесь, с ним ничего не случится. — козгров вернулся к столу и, немного помолчав, спросил: — скажите, вам никогда не приходило в голову показать сына хорошему детскому психологу? — вы с ума сошли! — закричала женщина, вскакивая на ноги. — корину не нужен никакой психолог! он абсолютно здоров! проблема не в нем, а в этой стерве! я должна была предвидеть, что мой приход бесполезен, что вы примете ее сторону. — я желаю корину добра. — директор старался сохранять спокойствие. — случай с хомяком — не единственный. в поведении вашего сына есть некоторые отклонения…